# Laravel + Vue Looping a Specific ID once

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hey guys so I'm planning to have a list of my recent chats. The problem is that i just want to loop the same Id (ex. Chatroom_id), in my case its looping the same the Chatroom Id 5 times, cause im checking a db that reciever_id is mine and the result is 5, hence the 5 times it loops the same Chatroom ID. I just want it to loop once ever chatroom Id

> Laravel View // where i insert my vue component

```
 <!--- Message or online followers and followings -->
   <div id="messagesidebar" class="app-sidebar-userdetails">   
       <h6 class="sm text-white"> <i> Recent Chat </i> </h6>

           <div id="recentchat">
              <recentchat-component :user_id="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></recentchat-component>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /# Message or online followers and followings  -->
       </div>
```

> Vue Template

```
  <div class="chats" v-for="recentchat in recentchats" v-bind:key="recentchat.id">

          {{ recentchat.chatroom_id}}


   </div>
```

> Laravel Controller

```
public function fetchrecentchat($user_id)
{
    $recentchat = Chat::Where('receiver_id', $user_id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();


    return ChatResource::collection($recentchat);
}
```

> Chat Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    // return parent::toArray($request);
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'message' => $this->message,
        'chatroom_id' => $this->chatroom_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'receiver_id' => $this->receiver_id,    
        'created_at' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),  
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,       
    ];
}
```

Tell me if you need to review codes that i did not add above so much thanks guys!

## Update

> Vue script

```
<script>
export default {
    props: [ 'user_id' ],
    data() {
        return {
        recentchats: [],
        recentchat: {
           id: '',
            chatroom_id: '',
             user_id: '',
              receiver_id: '',
               created_at: '',
                updated_at: '',
        }
     }

    },
    created() {
        this.fetchchatrooms();
    },
    methods: {
         fetchchatrooms(){
             fetch('/api/fetchrecentchat/' +this.user_id)
             .then(res => res.json())
             .then(res => {
                 console.log(res);
                 this.recentchats = res.data
             });
         }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Recent Chat mounted.')
    }
}
```

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim added it :)

Comment: does that array contain 5 chatroom duplicated?

Comment: yes, thats why its looping 5 times also

Comment: please provide a screenshot of what you're getting what you want to get

Comment: uhm im not on my desk right now, but this might help you understand what i want , So I just want to loop a chatroom ID once like 5, 3 , 4 not 5 , 5 ,5. cause im planning make it clickable then it will show all message in that chat room

Comment: i understand that you return 5 chatroom with different IDs for exemple 1,2..5 and you're getting 5 5 5 5 5